# How can I test if an Access VBA collection exists without using an error handler..?

Tags: ms-access, vba

When attempting to use the object Access.CurrentData.AllViews, I receive the following error:

```
Run-time error 2467:
The expression you entered refers to an object that is closed or doesn't exist.
```

This is as expected, since the database is not an ADP project, nor is it connected to an SQL database. I would like to test for the existence of AllViews (and similar collections), but I would like to avoid using an ErrorHandler if possible. I've tried various tests such as `IsMissing(`) and `Is Nothing`, but no luck. Attempting to test the `.Count` property won't work either; when the count is zero, the collection isn't there to perform any tests against.

For instance:

```
Dim av as Object
set av = Access.CurrentData.AllViews
```

Can the existence of such a collection be checked without using an error handler?

Comment: I don't think you can. What is wrong with using an error handler?

Comment: I think it's poor form. =-) A lot of programmers simply crash into an EH to test something, rather than using built-in VBA test functions. For instance, it's a common practice to test for the existence of a table or other object by trying to open it, and it if doesn't exist, crash into an EH and test for runtime error 3376 or similar. But I prefer to exercise more finesse and loop through the TableDefs collection to test for the table via the name property. And I frequently learn something new whilst I'm wandering through the hierarchy in the Object Explorer.

Comment: @spinjector. Assume you have 1000 ODBC tables, which is the fastest way? looping through 1000 tables or trying get an instance of that table by name and relying on EH? :) :)